# Using .htaccess to remove unwanted parts of a URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

To someone who knows what they're doing - tho will be really easy. all I want to do is remove a section of my urls, i assume that this is the easiest way.

This is how my URLs currently look:

```
/blog/?action=viewArticle&url=$postTile
```

I want to remove:

```
?action=viewArticle&url=
```

So that I end up with something like:

```
/blog/$postTitle
```

I've tried the below, but I've had no joy:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule   ^/bwc/(blog)/(.*)/$   /bwc/blog/?action=viewArticle&url=$2
```

Please help - I think I need to utilise MOD_REWRITE, but I'm not too sure how.

Answer (score 3):

I am not that sure but you please give a try with this

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ http://your_domain.com/blog/DateTimestamps-of-news-posts$1 [R=301,L]
```

See what comes with... :)

Comment: thanks for replying - i have also tried your implementation to no avail :(

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /site/blog/\?action=viewArticle&url=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /site/blog/%1? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^site/blog/([^/])+$ /site/blog/?action=viewArticle&url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

These rules need to be in the htaccess file in your document root.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the reply - it's probably worthwhile noting that my /blog/ folder is actually nested within a folder on a dev subdomain - so my url goes http://subdomain.domain.com/site/blog/?action=viewArticle&url=$postTile. 

I tried changing the obvious bits that I thought would work - but still nothing - with this in mind - what changes would I need to make?

Comment: @Jack Yeah, that information was vital as no solution would have been possible without knowing that

Comment: This is so frustrating. Still not making any difference - formatted exactly as you have suggested - http://dev.pixxl.us/bwc/blog/?action=viewArticle&url=Responsive-layouts there's a link - if you follow it - it stays that way! This mod_rewrite is starting to feel like more and more of a dark art!

Comment: I tell a lie - when I copy your code and change the /site/ to the correct folder name I get an error 500!